# get the value of column based on maximum value of a different column from a Pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like below:

```
   name  pid  cost   Date
0    a    1   800  1991-01-31
1    b    2   200  1991-01-31
2    c    3   300  1991-01-31
3    a    1   400  2001-01-31
4    b    4   500  2001-01-31
5    c    3   600  2001-01-31
```

I want to add a new column `maxCost` to this df based on the *latest* `Date` for the (name,pid) pair. So, the final output should be like this:

```
   name  pid  cost   Date      maxCost
0    a    1   800  1991-01-31   400
1    b    2   200  1991-01-31   200
2    c    3   300  1991-01-31   600
3    a    1   400  2001-01-31   400
4    b    4   500  2001-01-31   500
5    c    3   600  2001-01-31   600
```

I created a groupby object using

`df.groupby(['name','pid']).Date.max().reset_index()`

which gives me a dataframe like this:

```
   name  pid    Date
0    a    1  2001-01-31
1    b    2  1991-01-31
2    b    4  2001-01-31
3    c    3  2001-01-31
```

This gives me the correct dates for (name, pid) pair but how do I pull values from the cost column?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

**Note:** I did `reset_index()` just so it displays better in this post.

**Update**: The `maxCost` should look at the cost from latest date. Updating the cost on row index:0 from 100 to 800.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go `sort_values` before `transform` `first`

```
df=df.sort_values(['Date','cost'])
df['maxCost']=df.groupby(['name','pid'])['cost'].transform('last')
df=df.sort_index()
df
Out[775]: 
  name  pid  cost       Date  maxCost
0    a    1   800 1991-01-31      400
1    b    2   200 1991-01-31      200
2    c    3   300 1991-01-31      600
3    a    1   400 2001-01-31      400
4    b    4   500 2001-01-31      500
5    c    3   600 2001-01-31      600
```

Comment: This is a really awesome approach! Sorting and then taking the last of each group! Your solution works for me but can you please explain why are we sorting based on `Date` and `Cost`? As I just need to look at the cost for the latest date - I should be fine by just sorting values based on Date like `df=df.sort_values('Date')`. Right?

Comment: I take that back! Your solution is even more exhaustive than my simple mind initially comprehended. Yes, I'd like to take the maximum cost for the latest date if there're two costs for the same date. That would explain sorting based on Date & Cost! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you can use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) with `max`:

```
df['maxCost'] = df.groupby(['name', 'pid'])['cost'].transform('max')
```

[out]

```
  name  pid  cost        Date  maxCost
0    a    1   100  1991-01-31      400
1    b    2   200  1991-01-31      200
2    c    3   300  1991-01-31      600
3    a    1   400  2001-01-31      400
4    b    4   500  2001-01-31      500
5    c    3   600  2001-01-31      600
```

---

#### Edit

If you're looking to get the index of latest date and find the associated cost, you could instead use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['maxCost'] = (df.loc[df.groupby(['name', 'pid'])['Date']
                        .transform(lambda x: x.idxmax()), 'cost'].values)
```

[out]

```
  name  pid  cost       Date  maxCost
0    a    1   800 1991-01-31      400
1    b    2   200 1991-01-31      200
2    c    3   300 1991-01-31      600
3    a    1   400 2001-01-31      400
4    b    4   500 2001-01-31      500
5    c    3   600 2001-01-31      600
```

Comment: yes! This works perfectly! Thank you. Any advice on how to enhance my pandas skills?

Comment: honestly, the best way to sharpen up is to stick around here on SO! Watch the `pandas` tag and check back regularly to check out new questions and answers. Also check out some of highest voted questions and answers for some inspiration! Happy coding

Comment: I'm sorry! Your solution worked because of my 'contrived' example in which cost is always incrementing. If I change the cost for index 0 to 800, the maxCost should take value for `name` : `a` and `pid`: `1` as 400 because it comes from a more latest date (2001 vs 1991). I'm updating the initial df to include this scenario.